# NotificationListenerService and keeping device awake during work

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I'm extending the [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) in order to catch notifications being posted to the device. This has been working perfectly fine without doing anything special (like using wakelocks). I used to use a background thread to do some work (doing HTTP posts).

Lately I've started doing more work in the Service (about 1 sec CPU work on a Nexus 4 at wake) and I've dropped the background thread.

I've noticed that sometimes the device does not wake for doing the work, doing it minutes later or immediately when I turn the screen back on. I've added a partial wake-lock hoping it would solve the problem. Sadly it still shows random behavior.

Any idea how I can debug this any further and can anyone tell me whether my approach is correct?

```
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

static String wakeLockTag = "NotificationListenerWakeLock";

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {   
    acquireWakeLock();

    // Do work

    releaseWakeLock();
}

private void acquireWakeLock() {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    if (wakeLock == null) {
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, wakeLockTag);
    }

    if (!wakeLock.isHeld()) {
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }
}

private void releaseWakeLock() {
    if (wakeLock != null && wakeLock.isHeld())
        wakeLock.release();
}
```

Edit:

Looks like the wakelock gets released prematurely. It ends up in these two messages being spammed in LogCat for about 2 minutes:

```
02-11 20:12:19.557: D/dalvikvm(16564): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
02-11 20:12:19.617: D/dalvikvm(16564): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1032K, 10% free 19831K/21820K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 20ms
02-11 20:12:19.617: D/dalvikvm(16564): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
02-11 20:12:19.677: D/dalvikvm(16564): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1075K, 10% free 19794K/21820K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 17ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `onNotificationPosted` is indeed called ? Do you mean to say that before (that you were using a background thread) `onNotificationPosted` was called while now not ? This is rather improbable. Maybe you changed something else in your design. With this info the only logical assumption is that `onNotificationPosted` is simply not called when the phone is asleepbut you need the

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the garbage collector (I guess all the runs happen at once)

You could try to delegate to a [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful). It holds a wake lock that covers the gap between `onReceive()` and `doWakefulWork()`
which you must override. It will delegate to a thread and release the lock on completion. *If* `onNotificationPosted` wakes the CPU then you may need to use a WIS there.

But it seems more probable that simply the phone is not woken up

See:

- [PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321444/powermanager-partial-wake-lock-android/20332558#20332558)
- [wakeLock does not wait for network connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360571/wakelock-does-not-wait-for-network-connectivity/19384289#19384289)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've been fiddeling some more with my code. I've removed the wakelock and strangely enough it seems to be more stable now. No delays so far. Any idea how this is possible?

Comment: @ndsc: no idea - what you have to make sure is `onNotificationPosted` wakes the phone up - ask at google ? Once you do this make a minimal change in your code re-adding the locks (in a git branch say) and then check again. There is the possibility οf placebo effect with this all, so careful :)