# How to unlock device when service call

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

In my application, user starts the service it is open and it is called every 5 minutes. it works fine.
But I want to unlock automatically (call WAKE_LOCK )  whenever the service is called i.e. every 5 minutes.
How can I achieve this?

Any body please help me...

Edit 1#

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) { // obtain the wake lock 
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE); 
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, NAME); 

        mWakeLock.acquire();
    }
```

Comment: Did u mention this permission?? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Comment: Please have a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5549234/2591002). might help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the AlarmManager for that.

Set up of the alarm and its receiver : [Notification activity called by AlarmManager NOT to pop up when app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729833/notification-activity-called-by-alarmmanager-not-to-pop-up-when-app-is-closed/17752383#17752383)

Then you have to convert your service to a [wakeful intent service](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) and then call `WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, YourService.class);` inside `onReceive(context)`

At least this was the way to go  - the latest android platform seems to support this (kind of) out the box : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html